# Open slack app from a hyperlink (or URL scheme)

Tags: android, ios, slackware, slack

Is there a defined url-scheme which can be used to open the Slack app from a third-party app?

Comment: try to decode Slack apk and find the corresponding activity URI/Intent filter . That's what I always do. Or else, find an official documentation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I heard url schemes for Slack is not supported yet, but planned.

Although unofficial, you may try this,

```
slack://channel?id=<channel/group/user-id>&team=<team-id>
```

Comment: Thank you, looks promising to me.

Comment: This is now the official method. See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking) (mentioned in the other answer)

Answer (score 1):

Open Slack

```
 slack://open
```

Open a channel

```
 slack://channel?team={TEAM_ID}&id={CHANNEL_ID}
```

Open a direct message

```
 slack://user?team={TEAM_ID}&id={USER_ID}
```

Open a file

```
  slack://file?team={TEAM_ID}&id={FILE_ID}
```

source: https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking

example: slack://channel?team=U769JLSAV&id=C765NAL8G